# Angular web api routing

Tags: c#, .net, angular, sqlite, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on a angular web project where I have a angular site which communicates with a web api that uses a SQLlite database.

as I am new to angular, now I'm encountering a error where request are sent to the wrong port even though my proxy config is set to the api's port , where do I set the proper routing for traffic between my site and api/database.

The error I'm encountering while sending request:

```
Http failure response for http://localhost:4200/api/Account/AuthenticateUser: 404 Not Found
```

my proxy config:

```
{
"/api": {
  "target": "http://localhost:44366/",
  "secure": false,
  "changeOrigin": true,
  "logLevel": "debug"
}
```

}

sqllite:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8ZcO.png)

**Note: I'm continuing work from a pre existing project**

Comment: FIrst, consider removing "changeOrigin" property cause you still in localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was fixed by running the app in visual studio in release mode instead of debug mode

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use https try as below:

```
{
  "/api": {
     "target":  {
       "host": "localhost",
       "protocol": "https",
       "port": 44366
     },
     "secure": false,
     "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

and run it with a command:

```
ng serve --proxy-config ${your-proxy-file-name}.json --open --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check
```

Comment: I run the app locally through visual studio

Comment: So you have to create or edit run configuration for angular app.

Or execute command inside visual studio terminal (remember to execute command inside correct path)

Comment: I have followed all your recommendations but still am encountering the following error "[webpack-dev-server] [HPM] Error occurred while proxying request localhost:4200/api/Account/AuthenticateUser to undefined [ECONNRESET] (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)"

Comment: Can you try to switch to non-secured api (this one on port 50304)?
And also are you able to execute api request via browser or postman? (on both api servers)

Comment: yes, both browser and postman requests do work, I only encounter this error when trying to pass data through my website, also tested on the non-secured one, same problem

Comment: when you run your angular app do you see in console entries about created proxy like this:

Proxy created: /api  ->  http://someapi:1234

or

[HPM] Proxy created: /api/v2  -> [object Object]

if using the template from my answer

Comment: To update you, I have finally made progress, the problem was I was running the app in debug mode, all it took was to run it once in release mode and now I have proper traffic between my app and website, thanks for all the recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

**Use like :**

const routes: Routes = [
{
path: '',
component: StartScreenComponent,
pathMatch: "full"
},
{
path: 'login',
component: LoginComponent
},
{
path: 'welcome',
component: WelcomeComponent
},
]